# Change a different link color on mouseover

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a menu composed of multiple links, each followed by a descriptive paragraph. I need the paragraph to change color whenever the proper link is highlighted, and vice-versa.

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to do a:hover and it will change a different link than itself (ideally using CSS only, I'd like to avoid using JS or jQuery–if that is in fact possible at all).

Here's an example:

```html
<a class="title" href="page1.html">Page 1</a>
<hr/>
<a class="description" href="page1.html">Description of Page 1</a>
<br><br>
<a class="title" href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
<hr/>
<a class="description" href="page2.html">Description of Page 2</a>
<br><br>
<a class="title" href="page3.html">Page 3</a>
<hr/>
<a class="description" href="page3.html">Description of Page 3</a>
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: but whaere is the paragraph.. can u show us ur expected output as image?

Comment: The .description is the descriptive "paragraph". I wrote them as just <a> in my simplified example, but they could have been contained within a <p>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with pure CSS if you wrap the elements under one parent element (div,p,etc)

Remember to change the anchor styling so that it enables you to change the color. `a{color:inherit}`

```css
.colorChanger {
  color:green;
}
.colorChanger:hover {
  color:blue;
}
a{
  color:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'colorChanger'>
  <a class="title" href="page3.html">Page 1</a>
  <hr/>
  <a class="description" href="page3.html">Description of Page 1</a>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class = 'colorChanger'>
  <a class="title" href="page3.html">Page 2</a>
  <hr/>
  <a class="description" href="page3.html">Description of Page 2</a>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class = 'colorChanger'>
  <a class="title" href="page3.html">Page 3</a>
  <hr/>
  <a class="description" href="page3.html">Description of Page 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.title:hover + .description{
   <yourstyle>
}
```

but only when you remove your `<hr/>` as it only works on siblings immediately after

This is sooo much easier with Javscript/JQuery though, and wouldnt require you to change you markup to fit in with a CSS only solution

Answer (score 0):

you can do this... you just have to add a class to identify the pages!

```css
a.page_1:hover ~ a.description.page_1{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<a class="title page_1" href="page1.html">Page 1</a>
<hr/>
<a class="description page_1" href="page1.html">Description of Page 1</a>
<br><br>
<a class="title" href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
<hr/>
<a class="description" href="page2.html">Description of Page 2</a>
<br><br>
<a class="title" href="page3.html">Page 3</a>
<hr/>
<a class="description" href="page3.html">Description of Page 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wa1szd0q/1/)**

```
<div class="title active"><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a>

    <hr/>
    <p class="description">Description of Page 1</p>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="title"><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>

    <hr/>
    <p class="description">Description of Page 2</p>
</div>
<div class="title">
    <br>
    <br>
<a href="page3.html">Page 3</a>

    <hr/>
    <p class="description">Description of Page 3</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.title {
    color:green;
}
.title:hover>.description, .active>.description {
    color:red;
    background:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This css rule should do the job

```
.title:hover + .description {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: This selector will only target the direct next sibling, and will not work if there are elements separating them.